# Comparison of phrases containing the same word in Google Trends

Tags: seo, google, keywords, statistics

If I compare three phrases in [google trends](http://www.google.de/trends/explore#q=house,%20sale%20house,%20white%20house&cmpt=q) :

- house
- sale house
- white house

I get the following numbers:

- house -> 91
- sale house -> 3
- white house -> 2

The question is: Is "sale house" and "white house" already included in the number 91?

It is an important question, because if it is true, than:

- house_except_sale_house + sale_house = 91
- sale_house = 3

Which means I have to compare 88 and 3, if I compare "house" and "sale house"

Answer (score 1):

When you use just `house` it is not exact, it also talies broader queries that contain the term.  The documentation states:

> To compare up to 5 searches, separate them with commas: "table tennis", squash, handball
>
> To find any of several terms, separate them with plus signs: tennis + squash
>
> Put exact phrases in quotes: "table tennis"
>
> Put a minus sign before a word you don't want: wimbledon -tennis

Putting quotes around `"house"` doesn't make any difference as far as I can see, but using `house -sale -white` does reduce the numbers by the amount you would expect.